# How to define django-imagekit ImageSpecFields in parent/mixin class?

Tags: django, django-imagekit

I'm using [django-imagekit](https://django-imagekit.readthedocs.io/) to provide thumbnail versions of uploaded images on my Django models.

I would like to define various thumbnail `ImageSpecField`s in a mixin that my models can then inherit. However, each model currently has a different name for the `ImageField` on which its `ImageSpecField`s would be based.

I've tried this:

```py
from django.db import models
from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField
from imagekit.processors import ResizeToFit

class ThumbnailModelMixin(models.Model):
    IMAGE_SPEC_SOURCE_FIELD = None

    list_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(
        source=IMAGE_SPEC_SOURCE_FIELD,
        processors=[ResizeToFit((80, 160)],
        format="JPEG",
        options={"quality": 80}
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Book(ThumbnailModelMixin):
    IMAGE_SPEC_SOURCE_FIELD = "cover"
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to="books/")

class Event(ThumbnailModelMixin):
    IMAGE_SPEC_SOURCE_FIELD = "ticket"
    ticket = models.ImageField(upload_to="events/")
```

But this fails on page load with:

> AttributeError: 'Book' object has no attribute 'list_thumbnail'

Is there a way to get inheritance like this to work?

There are at least two other solutions:

1. Don't use a mixin/parent, and include the `ImageSpecField`s on each child class - a lot of duplicate code.
2. Change the `Book.cover` and `Event.ticket` fields to have the same name, like `image` and use `"image"` for the `ImageSpecField` `source` parameter.

The latter sounds best, but I'm still curious as to whether there's a way to get the inheritance working?

Comment: I ended up doing solution (2), changing the models' image field to `thumbnail`. I'd still like to know if it's possible to get it working otherwise though.

Comment: And I suspect it just isn't possible, judging by this similar answer I've finally found https://stackoverflow.com/a/17245249/250962